# Как работает стандартная анимация кнопки в Android Studio/SDK

Tags: android-studio

Я хотел воссоздать кнопку в Android SDK (Та которая при нажатия из место прикосновения выходит анимированный кружок)

Я попробовал просто скопировать из стандартного стиля XML

```
<item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button</item>
<item name="buttonStyleSmall">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small</item>
<item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button</item>

<item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton</item>

<item name="buttonBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar</item>
<item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog</item>
<item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
<item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
<item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
```

И кнопка с этим стилем работала как надо

Только я немогу понять как оно работает

Comment: Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос, приведя ваши попытки решить проблему? Это помогло бы Сообществу скорее помочь вам.

Comment: @DaemonHK, спасибо, так и сделал